# Who is calling reloadData method for UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

It can sounds weird but I don't understand why my tableView is showing cells.

I got array of items that should be shown in cells but I don't run `reloadData` method of my tableView anywhere in my code. It seems that some of app components or maybe frameworks inside app is calling `reloadData` method and I want to find out which one?

How it can be done?

Comment: why this is a problem? `reloadData` shouldn't be overridden (there is no reason).

Comment: the problem is that tableView is showing content before it is properly prepared

Comment: you are barking under wrong tree. Issue is most probably how you manage data to show and how you are handling notifications from `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45358597/1387438). It is OS X example, but pattern is the same (differences are minimal).

Comment: Just saw your comment about showing content before it is properly prepared. You should post a question specific to that issue. Include relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table view loads itself the first time it is added to the window hierarchy. You don't need an explicit call to `reloadData` for the table to load itself initially.

If you want to see how this is really done, put a breakpoint on your table view data source methods and bring up your table view. Look at the stack trace in the debugger to see the sequence of events.

Answer (score 1):

If your data preparation takes some time and you do not want the table view to show any data initially you could use an approach like this:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var someDataSource: [Any]!
    var dataSourcePrepared = false {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        guard dataSourcePrepared else { return 0 }
        return someDataSource.count
    }

    func doSomePreparationStuff() {
        // ...
        // ...
        someDataSource = ["Some", "Content"]
        dataSourcePrepared = true
    }

}
```

In this case I used a `Bool` variable `dataSourcePrepared` which is `false` initially. As soon as you have prepared your content set it to `true` and the table view gets reloaded.

Comment: There's a more direct solution. Get rid of `dataSourcePrepared` and make `someDataSource` a proper optional (with `?`).

Comment: @rmaddy Sure. If the non nil data source is the only criterium.